# Should I quote the company name if it is written in my language

Tags: sentence-structure

When using the name of Municipal Transport Services in my city that is written in my language should I put quotes around it?

I have clarified it before in the text somewhere else.

for example:

> The "Verkehrsbetriebe Bremen" runs the routes network in the city of Bremen.

Comment: In Russian, company names are often put inside quotation marks. When I translate, I use no quotation marks, and no **the** (usually). *Gazprom launches a new LGP processing plant in Far East*.

Answer (score 3):

In English, the **capitalisation** of a name makes it the **proper name** of *something*, quotation marks are not used:

> The **MTA** in New York City runs the buses and subways.
>   The **Verkehrsbetriebe Bremen** runs the routes network in the city of Bremen.
>   **Munchen Flughafen** is the major airport in Bavaria.

If you are using a foreign language name within English text, you can italicise it:

> The ***Verkehrsbetriebe Bremen*** runs the routes network in the city of Bremen.

this would be the same for any foreign language text:

> *Carpe diem* means "to seize the day".